# The parameter is incorrect - WinJs - launchFileAsync

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winjs

I am trying to open a PDF file using WinJS for a windows 8.1 application.

I am using the following code, but i am getting an error of

> The parameter is incorrect

But i am sure i am doing it all fine

```
// example filePath = 'previews\\preview.pdf'
function (filePath) {

    rootFolder.getFileAsync(filePath).then(function (file) {
        var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
        options.displayApplicationPicker = true;

        Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file, options).then(function (success) {
            if (success) {
                successCallback();
            } else {
                errorCallback();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The file exists, and when i debug, i get to line

```
Windows.System.Launcher.launchFileAsync(file, options).then(function
```

but then the error is thrown

I am currently running this on a windows 8.1 development laptop.

Any clues?

Comment: Are you sure your path should be with a forward slash or should it have been  filePath = "previews\\preview.pdf"?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, i typed the wrong slashes.  I have edited this.  As i said, the file is found, but getting the error when trying to launch

Answer (score 0):

The error `The parameter is incorrect` is thrown if it cannot find the file or Uri. You need to use a **backslash** in your file path instead of the **forward** **slash**

```
filePath = "previews\\preview.pdf"
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake, i typed the wrong slashes.  I have edited this.  As i said, the file is found, but getting the error when trying to launch